# Query AWS-Glue metadata (column comment and table description) with redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, metadata, aws-glue, amazon-redshift-spectrum

My table's metadata is on Glue, with a description and comments on the columns, as it shows at the picture bellow.
I would like to retrieve these data through Redshift. Is it possible...? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: This would be a good feature! (sorry I do not have an answer except that you could process the glue metadata using a script outside of redshift, in that script write it to redshift and/or an s3 folder)

Comment: =( oh crap, thanks so much, this already gives us a great guideline to how to procceed. We were thinking about creating a table on S3 with all these information, so redshift could access it...